# Problem about decomposition of modular space into eigenspace

Tags: representation-theory, modular-forms

It is said we can use the operator
$$
\pi_\chi=\frac{1}{\phi(N)}\sum_{d\in\mathbb{Z}_N^*}\chi(d)^{-1}\langle d\rangle
$$

to project function in $\mathcal{M}_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ into the $\chi-$eigenspace $\mathcal{M}_k(N,\chi)$.

I just down know what the symbol $\langle d\rangle$ means here. Does it mean a cyclic group? If so, how does this operator work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\langle d\rangle$ is the Diamond operator. See e.g. [these notes](http://wstein.org/books/ribet-stein/main.pdf) of William Stein, or pretty much any other source on modular forms that covers Hecke operators.